Spring Boot Start Up error java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid block type
When I restart the server and start the jar, the following error occurs:
Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception
cn.hutool.crypto.CryptoException: SecurityException: JCE cannot authenticate the provider BC
    at cn.hutool.crypto.digest.mac.DefaultHMacEngine.init(DefaultHMacEngine.java:105)
    at cn.hutool.crypto.digest.mac.DefaultHMacEngine.<init>(DefaultHMacEngine.java:56)
    at cn.hutool.crypto.digest.mac.MacEngineFactory.createEngine(MacEngineFactory.java:42)
    at cn.hutool.crypto.digest.HMac.<init>(HMac.java:86)
    at cn.hutool.crypto.digest.HMac.<init>(HMac.java:74)
    at cn.hutool.crypto.digest.HMac.<init>(HMac.java:63)
    at cn.hutool.jwt.signers.HMacJWTSigner.<init>(HMacJWTSigner.java:28)
    at cn.hutool.jwt.signers.JWTSignerUtil.createSigner(JWTSignerUtil.java:136)
    at cn.hutool.jwt.signers.JWTSignerUtil.hs256(JWTSignerUtil.java:36)
    at cn.hutool.jwt.JWT.setKey(JWT.java:120)
    at com.prod4arraycomm.oam.layer.l5system.security.filter.JwtAuthenticationTokenFilter.doFilterInternal(JwtAuthenticationTokenFilter.java:48)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:103)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:89)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:91)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:112)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:82)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:55)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter.doFilterInternal(DisableEncodeUrlFilter.java:42)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:221)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:186)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:354)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:267)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:96)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:360)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:890)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1789)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: JCE cannot authenticate the provider BC
    at javax.crypto.JceSecurity.getInstance(JceSecurity.java:118)
    at javax.crypto.Mac.getInstance(Mac.java:257)
    at cn.hutool.crypto.SecureUtil.createMac(SecureUtil.java:1055)
    at cn.hutool.crypto.digest.mac.DefaultHMacEngine.init(DefaultHMacEngine.java:95)
    ... 61 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid block type
    at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:164)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.jar.ZipInflaterInputStream.read(ZipInflaterInputStream.java:52)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:284)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:345)
    at javax.crypto.JarVerifier.verifySingleJar(JarVerifier.java:469)
    at javax.crypto.JarVerifier.verifyJars(JarVerifier.java:363)
    at javax.crypto.JarVerifier.verify(JarVerifier.java:289)
    at javax.crypto.JceSecurity.verifyProviderJar(JceSecurity.java:164)
    at javax.crypto.JceSecurity.getVerificationResult(JceSecurity.java:190)
    at javax.crypto.JceSecurity.getInstance(JceSecurity.java:114)
    ... 64 common frames omitted

The probability of this problem is very low, and if I restart the process, it will not report an error, has anyone experienced similar problems?
My springboot version is 2.7.3, jdk version is 1.8.0_202-b08, and the server is Ubuntu
